# Error: Keyboard cannot be resolved

Tags: java

I want to write a simple program that reads an array from the keyboard and paste it on the screen. When I compile it, I get the following error:

```
Keyboard cannot be resolved
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

    public class Test2
    {
        public static void main (String args[])
        {
            int i, n;
            int[] myList= new int[100];
            System.out.println ("n= "); Keyboard.getInt(n);
            for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                System.out.println ("myList[" + i + "]= ");
                Keyboard.getInt(myList[i]);
            }
            for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
                System.out.println (myList[i]);
        }

    }
```

I'm working with Eclipse Luna. Do I need to download any package to use the function Keyboard.getInt?
Thank you!

Comment: Indeed.. What is `Keyboard`?

Comment: There are many ways to read data from the keyboard. For example:

 1)InputStreamReader
 2)Console
 3)Scanner
 4)DataInputStream etc.
ButI never heard about keyboard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to create the `keyboard` variable of type `Scanner`.

Add this at the beginning:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Some things to keep in mind:

- variable names start in lowercase so change your `Keyboard` to `keyboard`. see the [Oracle naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)
- `Scanner` has the `nextInt` method which returns `int`.
- you should close the `Scanner` at the end.
- arrays are zero based, you should begin from 0 up to `n - 1`

So you will get:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test2
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int i, n;
        int[] myList= new int[100];
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("n= ");
        n = keyboard.nextInt();
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            System.out.println ("myList[" + i + "]= ");
            myList[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            System.out.println (myList[i]);

        keyboard.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: (and also correct their own declaration to lowercase)

Comment: I think the OP is using something like [Keyboard.java](http://duke.csc.villanova.edu/jss1/bookResources/keyboard.jsp).

Answer (score 1):

use scanner class like this 
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)
and in your loop put keyboard.next() instead Keyboard.getInt()
here is sample code:

```
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int i, n;
        int[] myList= new int[100];
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner();
        System.out.println ("n= ");
        n = keyboard.next();
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            System.out.println ("myList[" + i + "]= ");
            mylist[i] = keyboard.next();
        }
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            System.out.println ("list values" + myList[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes like Scanner or Console are probably what you want (see other answers for details). If you need low level access to key events, I do not know of any cross platform library, but under Linux [evdev-java](https://github.com/progman32/evdev-java) works fairly well.